# Ambiguity issue: Dressed up as for Halloween

Tags: word-choice

I think this statement can be interpreted in two ways:

> What did you dress up as for Halloween? (What costume did you wear
>   for Halloween?)
>
> Why did you dress up as for Halloween? (Why did you dress up as if
>   it was Halloween?)

If I'm right, is "what" and "why" enough to remove the ambiguity? Or maybe using "like" would be better to remove the ambiguity? (e.g. Why did you dress up like for Halloween?)

Comment: I suggest the difference here is as basic as the difference between ***What** did he ask?* and ***Why** did he ask?*. If it belongs anywhere, this should be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There's no ambiguity between *What* and *Why*. The difficulty comes from the odd construction with *why*: using ***as if*** in that sentence would be more idiomatic. Without the *if,* one's first thought is that the *Why* should be *What* because that's the normal question-word **with that construction.** If there is an ambiguity, it's because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to maintain that second sentence try a comma:

> Why did you dress up, as for Halloween?

A clearer approach would be

> Why did you wear your Halloween costume?